# Windows Azure Deployment - not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I created MVC 4 application with Web API. It works good in local environment. When I deployed it to Azure, it gives following error.

Exception information:
Exception type: HttpException
Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor() at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters() at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters(HttpConfiguration config) at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes) at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration() at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) at Activity.Web.Monitor.UI.MvcApplication.Application_Start()

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" because CLR found another version of Newtonsoft.json while it was looking for ver 6.0.

This happens because your application is referencing another version of Newtonsoft.Json and some other dependency on the application uses version 6.0 of Newtonsoft.json. If you drill down through the .cspkg (use 7zip) and extract the Newtonsoft.json from siteroot\0\bin, you will get to know which version of Newtonsoft is included on the package.

Verify on the project references to see if CopyLocal is set to `true` or not for Netonsoft.json. Also, on web.config, add an [assembly redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure call for any older version of Newtonsoft.json gets redirected to required version.

Comment: The installed version is 7.0, and am not sure why its searching for version 6.0. How can I overcome this?

Comment: this happens because some other reference you added needs newtonsoft.json ver 6. add an assembly redirection on web.config so that all probes for ver 6 will be redirected to ver 7. link on my answer shows everything you need to know about assembly redirection.

Comment: 7.0.1.18622 is the actual dll version. But in packages.config it look likes below.

Comment: The actual dll version is 7.0.1.18622
Packages.cofig looks like as follows
`<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />`

I updated the web.config as follows

`<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

But still it is not working.

Comment: Just add an assembly redirection and it should work. But do verify what gets included on your cspkg

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to verify cspkg?

Comment: cspkg is a zip file so you can either change the extension to .zip or if you have 7-Zip installed, you can drill down through the file. Extract the Newtonsoft.json from it to verify the version.

Comment: Thanks for your time and support. It worked. Also I deleted azure project and readded it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in your solution there is another version of Newtonsof.json. You need to delete your neftonsoft.json file and replace it with the right veersion (6.0.0.0)

Comment: Currenlyt it has version 7.0.0.0 , How to get version 6.0.0.0 installed for same project>

Comment: in that case, you can uninstall the package with ver 7 and install ver 6. Uninstall-Package <package name> and Install-Package <package name> -Version <version> commands on nuget package manager console will get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the update. 7.0.1.18622 is the actual version of dll.