# Azure Mobile Services & Newtonsoft.Json 7

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-mobile-services

I recently upgraded Newtonsoft.Json in my project from version 6(.0.6) to 7(.0.1).
When i tried to publish the project to Azure i got an unhealthy service and the following message in the Logs:

ERROR

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json': 6.0.0.0, 7.0.0.0. Please change your
>   project to use version '6.0.0.0' which is the one currently supported
>   by the hosting environment.

Does that mean that azure doesn't support Newtonsoft.Json 7, or am i doing something wrong? Have i forgot something? If azure doesn't support version 7 is there a workaround? I must use thath version because i am trying to install a 3rd party package that requires it.

Comment: This help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445438/windows-azure-deployment-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json

Comment: I have read this answer and added an assembly redirection. Didn't help

Comment: Could you post the `Package.config` here.,

Comment: i can't do that. How would it help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services has specific hosted versions of its NuGet packages and dependencies and does its own binding redirects at runtime. Unfortunately, this means you have to use Newtonsoft 6.0.4. This is specified as a dependency in the nuspec for WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend/

What I recommend instead is that you use [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-preview/) which removes this limitation. Mobile Apps is still in preview, but we recommend that customers building a new app start here. Mobile Apps is part of App Service and provides all of the benefits of that platform, such as VNET/VPN, backup and restore, more scale options, more CI options, WebJobs, etc.